# Time Machine keeps asking me to create a new backup, even after I fixed the sparsebundle

Tags: backup, time-machine, macos, osx-server, server.app

I repaired my Sparsebundle on my Time Machine server [using these instructions](http://www.garth.org/archives/2011,08,27,169,fix-time-machine-sparsebundle-nas-based-backup-errors.html). I edited the `com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.plist` file and the `com.apple.TimeMachine.MachineID.bckup` as one of the commenters on that post said that was necessary for his to backup to work again.

However, just moments after starting up the backup, I get the Time Machine error that my last verification failed and I need to create a new backup.

I checked my `plist` file and Time Machine changed the `VerificationState` from `0` to `2`, obviously without performing another verification.

It seems as if Time Machine is reverting to a previous `plist` file, or there are other places changes must be made to continue backups. I followed the steps exactly in the post, but still cannot backup to my sparsebundle.

I also tried removing the `plist` and `bckup` files, re-running the backup, but the files were simply recreated nearly instantly, and moments later I got the same error that my last verification failed and I need to create a new backup.

I am running macOS Sierra. What could I be missing?

*Other users on Ask Different have suggested that my question is a duplicate of [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56063/time-machine-keeps-asking-to-create-new-backup), but it is not. I understand why Time Machine initially asked me to create a new backup. I have found that many people have solved the initial problem by [using these instructions](http://www.garth.org/archives/2011,08,27,169,fix-time-machine-sparsebundle-nas-based-backup-errors.html), however there appears to be more to it. The top upvoted answer suggests I follow the same instructions I have already followed, and while I was able to repair the sparsebundle, my specific issue is that Time Machine does not recognize the `plist` setting reset and immediately asks me to create a new backup. **The question is why won't my `plist`settings take affect and allow me to run a backup?***